# Use Navigator in React Native + Redux

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-redux

I'm new to React Native.
I have a React Native app using the Redux framework. I'm using the Navigator component to handle navigation but this.props.navigator is undefined in component. How can I pass "this.props.navigator" to component? 
I'm not able to find any good examples of how to do it correctly so I'm looking for some help and clarification.

**index.anroid.js**

```
...
import App from './app/app';

AppRegistry.registerComponent('RnDemo', () => App);
```

**app.js**

```
...    
import App from './containers/app';

const logger = createLogger();
const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(thunk, logger)(createStore);
const store = createStoreWithMiddleware(rootReducer);

const rootApp = () => {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  )
}

export default rootApp;
```

**containers/app.js**

```
...
class App extends Component {

  renderScene(route, navigator) {
    let Component = route.component
    return (
      <Component navigator={navigator} route={route} />
    )
  }

  configureScene(route) {
    if (route.name && route.name === 'Home') {
      return Navigator.SceneConfigs.FadeAndroid
    } else {
      return Navigator.SceneConfigs.FloatFromBottomAndroid
    }
  }

  _selectPage(page) {
    if(page === 'detail') {
      this.props.navigator.push({
        component: Detail,
        name: 'Detail'
      }) // **this.props.navigator.push is not a function**
    }
  }
  render() {
    const { navigator } = this.props;
    console.log(navigator);  // **>>>>>> Undefined**
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.menu}>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this._selectPage('detail')}><View style={styles.menuItem}><Text>Detail</Text></View></TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.content}>
          <Navigator
            ref='navigator'
            style={styles.navigator}
            configureScene={this.configureScene}
            renderScene={this.renderScene}
            initialRoute={{
              component: Home,
              name: 'Main'
            }}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
renderScene(route, navigator) {
    let Component = route.component
    return (
        // <Component navigator={navigator} route={route} />
        <Component {...this.props} navigator={navigator} route={route} />
    )
}
```

Try it